# Have 2 different UIViews determine the height of the contentView of a UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

Is it possible to have 2 different `UIView`s connected to the bottom of the `ContentView` of the `UIScrollView` and toggle them at the click of a button?

The hierarchy of Views I have right now -

```
UIScrollView
   ContentView
     UIView1
     UIView2
```

What I exactly wish to achieve is to have both `UIView1` and `UIView2` connected to the bottom of the ContentView and switch between the two cases programatically.

I tried making one of the 2 constraints optional and then switching priorities according to my cases but it says I can't change the priories of already loaded views to required from optional (or vice versa).

Comment: Yes you can.First of all, you can't change scrolls `contentSize` with help of  constraints. Constraints are basically designed to calculate frame of any view, not content size. You have to provide the content size of scroll view. System won't calculate it automatically. Adjust `scrollView`'s content size according to your 2 views. You can change scroll views `contentOffset` with or without animation to scroll from one offset to another.

Comment: There's some confusion here... 1st, absolutely, you can use constraints to control the contentSize of scroll views. 2nd, it's not quite clear what you are asking: Do you want to toggle between showing one view and hiding the other? Or do you want to swap their positions?

Comment: @DonMag I wish to toggle the contentSize of the UIScrollView between the heights of 2 different UIViews

Comment: OK, then yes, you were on the right track. Connect both `UIView1` and `UIView2` to the bottom of `ContentView`, and create @IBOutlets for the constraints. As @Saurav says in his answer, give then priorities *other than* 1000. So, if you want to start with View1 controlling the size, then (for example) set V1 to 999 and V2 to 998. When desired, just swap values - set V1 to 998 and V2 to 999.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the priories of already loaded views to required from optional. but you can definitely increase the priority in the same range. example- priority1 = 750 ,priority2 = 760